# Expression Engine Extension Development - Add custom javascript to rendered entry

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

I'm working on an extension and one of the options available in the settings needs a custom javascript to be added to the document head when rendered. The problem I am having is with the parsing order. (There may also be a better way of doing the include too)

I am using the `channel_entries_tagdata` hook.

Inside this, once the settings are processed, I am doing the following:

```
// Add the required javascript
$jscript = "
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*! etc......
    </script></head>
";

// Add js
$tagdata = str_replace("</head>", $jscript, $tagdata);
```

I would like to be able to just keep my javascript in a separate file and include it somehow by reference, but I don't know how to do that at this stage.

The other issue I am running into is the parsing order of the EE variables. Inside the javascript, I am using the variables from the $tagdata. Something like this:

```
$.post("URL", { channel: "{channel}", entryId: "{entry_id}", urlTitle: "{url_title}", lastSegment: "{last_segment}", editDate: eo.editDate, field: eo.eleName }, function(data){...
```

How would I call/use the EE variables in this case?

Elaborated...
This extension is for the following:
In the Addons -> Extensions from the control panel, they will activate the extension. In the 'Settings' for that extension, they will be able to authorize, by Channel, the members or groups that can 'edit' entries in that channel.

The extension, after checking permissions, edits each custom field type before it is rendered and wraps it in a class element. The JavaScript file is for this functionality next. When that element is clicked, a modal is opened which will contain the custom field type as well as the channel/entry information, so it can save the field once edited.

Answer (score 0):

Could you let the script in the `<head>` be a generic function and pass variables to it by calling it from inside your channel entries?

```
<head>
  ...
  <script>
    function W3bGuy_function(channel, entry_id, last_segment) {
      ...whatever...
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  ...
  {exp:channel:entries}
  some action triggers: W3bGuy_function('{channel}', '{entry_id}', '{segment_3}');
  {/exp:channel:entries}
  ...
```

Comment: This leaves me in the same boat. It won't have any "user input", just the settings in the extension themselves. So specifying the action within the template still requires me to edit the $tagdata and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Let's go up a level. What are you trying to achieve?  User comes to a page and... (might be best to append to your question).

Answer (score 0):

`channel_entries_tagdata` contains the raw template code pulled from within each `{exp:channel:entries}` loop, and then has another variable ($row) which is an array of the actual data for that entry. (As per [the docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel-entries-tagdata).)

So first, you'll have to make sure your entire page template is within your Channel Entries loop if you want to add JS to the `<head>` in this manner - and that may not work if your `<head>` is inside an embed.

Second, I'd suggest dumping the `$row` data that's passed via that hook, to see if you can extract your data in your returned JS from there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I didn't think about the first section. That's a good point. I can move my js to the end of the page without issue so that shouldn't be problematic.

"Second, I'd suggest dumping the $row data that's passed via that hook, to see if you can extract your data in your returned JS from there."

This is where I keep bumping into roadblocks. I am trying to utilize the tagdata in the js. If I code things in the template, they run fine. I just can't seem to find the right spot during parsing to catch and input the changes.

Comment: Maybe start with a really simple, non-JS test for modifying tagdata and variables within, to see what works and what doesn't? (No experience using this hook myself.)